# Two `minipage` inside command

Tags: macros, minipage

I want two `minipages` side-by-side.  I can do this easily.  But then I want to turn it into a command, and the `minipages` don't line up any more, even thought the code looks identical.

[image: problem]

What is wrong?  In the MWE i show what I want without the command, and then try to put it into command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dualminipage}[2][]
{
\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.45\linewidth}
#1
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.45\linewidth}
#2
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
% Firstly the minipages put simply.
\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.45\linewidth}
This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. 
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.45\linewidth}
This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. 
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.5in}
% Now the minipages put into a command

\dualminipage {
This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. This is the left-hand side. 
}
{
This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. This is the right-hand side. 
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\newcommand{\dualminipage}[2]
{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}#2\end{minipage}
}
```

It seems that second square backed in your`\dualminipage` definition make a problem.